# JQuery Datepicker in a JQuery popup

Tags: jquery

How is it possible to create an JQuery Datepicker in a Popup? 
I have tried many things, but it does not seems to work. Of course I can not use $(document).ready, because the popup is loaded inside JQuery like this

```
function PopupCallback(data) {
  $('#popup').show();
  $('#popup .content').html(data.Content);
}
```

data is loaded from AJAX

Comment: You should definitely be able to. Can you post some more code outlining what you tried to do?

Comment: What kind of "Popup" are you wanting to add this to? A browser new window? A Jquery Modal? A msgbox?

Comment: @tobias86 I can't as the JQuery shows the popup. I can put some more code to the question, when I come home

Comment: @ScruffyTheJanitor The popup is loaded as something like a floating div

Comment: @The87Boy Please let me know if the answer I posted does not suit your needs.

Comment: @ScruffyTheJanitor I am sorry, that I haven't answered you question, but I didn't have the time for it. It doesn't solve my problem, but I have found a solution by using
function PopupCallback(data) {
  $('#popup').show();
  $('#popup .content').html(data.Content);
  $("#datepicker").datePicker();
}

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `JQueryui` already, the simple way to do this is to wrap your `Datepicker` in a `jquery modal dialog`.

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Wrapped with Jquery Modal Dialog.

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title='Basic modal "Popup" dialog'>
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            modal: true
    });
});
```

[See this Fiddle for a working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XmdfK/6/)

Modal Dialog Documentation - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Datepicker Documentation - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline